# Timer stopped working after update to Xcode 7.3/Swift 2.2

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7.3, swift2

After updating to Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3, my repeating NSTimer has stopped repeating.

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(rotate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
timer.fire()
```

Selector fires once, then won't fire again until after window closes or is minimized.

Anyone else? Any suggestions?

Comment: It fires once, but never again. Sorry, thought I said that.

Comment: Still won't repeat. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval:1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(self.rotate), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }
```

It's a threading issue as well as either not properly being added or processing within NSRunLoop automatically. Manually doing this on the same thread fixed it.

Thanks everyone for help and recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

Timers need to be always scheduled or invalidated in the same thread, may be you're calling it inside an async block? Try schedule it in the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(rotate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()
    })
```

Comment: Calling it in my viewDidLoad(). What's weird is it worked before I updated to 7.3 and my timer will fire ONLY after the window closes.

Comment: I know, I've had the same problem with a single timer inside the project I'm working on... dispatch_async did the trick for me...

Comment: Still won't repeat. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I fixed it, you were close! It's not just a thread problem, but it's also NSRunLoop

Comment: Glad I helped a bit, in fact the thread problem is about the runloop thread, but can you let us know how you solved the problem specifically? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
func startTimer() {
    let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```

This works for me in Swift 2.2
Apples documentation doesn't say anything about dispatch_async. Is there any reason to use it...just curious...still learning

> Use the timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: class method to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)